Size of a pointer variable in C language
What is the size of a pointer variable in C and how is it assigned? We all know pointers store the address of the variable. The length of address may vary depending on system-to-systems as main-memory size changes (from laptops- 6-8GBs to embedded controllers - in few kB). So, accordingly, the length of the pointer variable may also change. So, will the size of the pointer variable change for the above two cases or remain the same?
Code:
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    short int a = 9;
    short int *p1=&a;
    double b = 10;
    double *p2=&b;
    printf("Size of integer = %d\n",sizeof(*p1));
    printf("Size of double = %d\n",sizeof(*p2));
    printf("Size of integer pointer = %d\n",sizeof(p1));
    printf("Size of double pointer = %d\n",sizeof(p2));
    printf("Value of integer pointer = %x\n",p1);
    printf("Value of integer pointer = %x", p2);
}

**Output:**
Size of integer = 2
Size of double  = 8
Size of integer pointer = 4
Size of double pointer  = 4
Value of integer pointer = 61ff16
Value of integer pointer = 61ff08



The size of the pointer does not depend on what it points to - int/double/... (an address is an address). But it does depend on the system/architecture.

@wohlstad The size of the pointer may depend on what it points to. There is no guarantee in the standard that all pointers have the same size. There are implementations (not very common these days) where void* is bigger than int* for example.

@n.m.couldbeanAI I never encountered such a system, but I stand corrected about the guarantee in the standard.

Unrelated: use "%p" to print the value of a pointer to void: printf("Value of integer pointer = %p\n", (void*)p1);

Using %d to print a sizeof value, which has type size_t, is incorrect.  Use %zu instead.

Info: In old DOS, we had different memory models (16 or 32 bit for code and same for data addresses). So some of the memory models differ between pointer to code (functions) and to data.

See Correct format specifier to print pointer or address?

In a normal C implementation, the size(s) of pointers are heavily influenced by the architecture and the operating system it targets. However, ultimately the sizes are determined by the C implementation, not the hardware.
What you will most commonly but not always see is that, on a “32-bit system”1 (one where general processor registers are 32 bits and the hardware address space is not wider than 32 bits), pointers are 32 bits (four eight-bit bytes), and, on a “64-bit system” (one where general processor registers are 64 bits and the hardware address space is wider than 32 bits), pointers are 64 bits (eight eight-bit bytes). However, this is not a rule of the C standard, and there are exceptions.
I have seen a compiler targeted for a 64-bit system but providing 32-bit pointers, for the purpose of building programs with smaller memory use. (It had been observed that the sizes of pointers were a considerable factor in memory consumption, due to the use of many structures with many connections and references using pointers.) I have also seen pointers wider than the hardware address because they contained extra information, such as bits for pointer authentication. Another reason a C implementation might use pointers that are not a “natural” fit to the hardware is to support old code that was written for a specific pointer size.
The C standard does not even require that pointers of different types have the same size. A C implementation might have different sizes for pointers to functions than it does for pointers to data. A C implementation for hardware with word-addressable memory (not byte-addressable) might have one size of pointer for int * (because it only needs enough bits to select the word from memory) and another size of pointer for char * (because it needs extra bits to select the byte from the word).
The C standard requires:

Pointers to character types and pointer to void must be the same size.
Pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types must be the same size.
Pointers to structures must be the same size.
Pointers to unions must be the same size.

Other than those, different types of pointers may have different sizes. So the short int * and the double * in your sample code may have different sizes.
Footnote
1 I put “32-bit system” and “64-bit system” in quotes because there is no specific definition for a 32-bit system or a 64-bit system. There are multiple processor features that may have different widths, including general register width, bus width, hardware address width, and virtual memory address width.


So, will the size of the pointer variable change for the above two cases or remain the same?

Yes, in C, the size of a pointer variable is allowed to vary across different CPU architectures.
If you run your sample code on a computer of a different CPU architecture, it is likely that it will print different sizes for the pointers.
This is because C is the epitome of an efficient programming language, and in computer science, a programming language is said to be efficient if the size of its data types matches the size of the machine word. (See Word (Computer Architecture) on Wikipedia.)
This understanding of efficiency stems from statements such as the following:

The efficiency of a program is closely tied to the machine on which it is run, and an important factor is how well the program uses the machine's resources, such as its word size, registers, and memory hierarchy.

— Donald Knuth, The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 1: Fundamental Algorithms.
but more importantly:

A programming language is efficient if it allows a program to be written that runs efficiently on a given machine. Efficiency here means that the program uses the machine's resources effectively, such as its processor speed, memory, and particularly its word size.

— Hal Abelson, Gerald Jay Sussman, Julie Sussman, Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs.

If the CPU you are compiling for has a 64-bit architecture, then most likely you will be dealing with sizeof(void*) = 8 (64 bits = 8 bytes) as well as sizeof(int*) = 8, sizeof(double*) = 8 and the same for any other pointer type.
The CPU can have a different architecture like a 32-bit architecture, in which case in most scenarios you'll get sizeof(void*) = 4, sizeof(int*) = 4, sizeof(double*) = 4, etc. (32 bits = 4 bytes). There may be some exceptions to this rule out there in the wild, and if you are not sure with a specific compiler and a target system, you can always make a check by using sizeof() in your C code or in the build system configuration and handle that as needed.

Refer processor architecture guide to get this information. It varies processor to processor.
